# Extracting <CRLF>-Strings from a ByteBuffer - I'm getting all confused

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I've been sitting with this problem for some hours now without getting it to work the way I want it to work.

I'm creating a server which reads data from a telnet client. The server uses java.nio (ServerSocketChannel) and reads into a ByteBuffer. After each read() I'm calling a method which is suppose to extract all lines (seperated by "\r\n") from the ByteBuffer and leave the (if any) remaining bytes in a way so the next read() puts them in the correct position.

Example:

read() reads 6 bytes, the ByteBuffer now contains "Hi\r\nHo". What I want to do is to extract all completely recieved strings, in this example "Hi\r\n". I want to "Ho" to be left in the ByteBuffer, shifted so that the "H" is at position 0, so that when I call read() next time and recieve "w are you?\r\n", it will be put at the correct place in the ByteBuffer.

I created a small test program but I can't seem to get it to do it correct: http://pastebin.com/eun1nV2N

Try different test strings ("HI", "HI\r\n", "HI\r\nHEY\r", etc) and you'll see when it fails. (I used the eclipse debug tool to inspect variables)

Comment: Try this class: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/LineReader.html

Comment: take a look at: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/bytebuffer.html

Comment: I got it to work without wrapping it as an InputStream: http://pastebin.com/Fua0NYpG - I just call that method until it returns null.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the ByteBuffer an InputStream and a BufferedReader, then you should be able to use readline to get the lines one by one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flip the buffer.
2. Call get() until you have the \r\n, storing the get() result of course.
3. Compact the buffer.